# Bivariate normal distribution when $\rho$ is 0

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

What happens to the bivariate normal distribution when $\rho$ is 0?The bi-variate normal reduces to a simpler distribution, but what is it? and how do you calculate the cdf then?

What I have tried:

When $\rho$ is 0, the bivariate normal distribution becomes independent normal cdf. Cdf then be calculated by normal cdf. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the random variables that follow the normal distribution. Let the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ be the bivariate normal distribution.
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\left(1-\rho^2\right)}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}-\frac{2\rho(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right]\right)}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}},
$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$. The definition of the correlation is
$$
\rho_{X,Y}=\frac{\text{Cov}[X,Y]}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}.
$$
If $\rho_{X,Y}=0$, then $\text{Cov}[X,Y]=0$, which means $X$ and $Y$ is **independent**. Hence, the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ can be written as
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y).
$$
**Proof :**

$$
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\left(1-0^2\right)}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}-\frac{2(0)(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}\right]\right)}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-0^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_x}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_y}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)\\
&=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y).&\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}
$$
The distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is still bivariate normal distribution, more details the independent bivariate normal distribution. The CDF of $X$ and $Y$ can be calculated as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}[X\le x,Y\le y]=F_{X,Y}(x,y)&=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x f_{X,Y}(u,v)\ du\,dv\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x f_{X}(u)\ du\int_{-\infty}^yf_{Y}(v)\ dv,
\end{align}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are just the dummy variables that substitute $x$ and $y$.

### $$\\$$

$$\large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$